# How To Understand Call Hierarchy Under Threads In Xcode

Tags: xcode

Sorry about the title if it causes confusion because I really don't know how to express my problem.

Anyway, I am wondering what does this number mean?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the frame number. The elements of the stack are stack frames. Xcode is showing you the frames of the stack with a 0-based index next to each one.

Xcode is eliding some frames which it thinks are probably uninteresting. That's what the dotted line between frames 0 and 4 represents. It has hidden frames 1 through 3 (and, further down, 15 through 17). I think there's a slider to govern how aggressive Xcode is in hiding frames, which you can adjust if that bothers you. Or maybe it's now just a button to turn that on and off.